# What is an efficient way to upload csv files from a VM to bigquery

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-python-api

**Question**

Is there a more efficient way I can use to streamline a process of uploading csv files to bigquery from a python script or any other way?

**Description**

I have 1528596 CSV files which needs to be uploaded to bigquery [Tables are created already]. My current approach is proven to be [slow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTiXf.png), which I think is  due to google bigquery [upload quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#api_requests). Going above the [quota](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#api_requests) gives me the following exceptions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “name_of_file.py", line 220, in <module>
  File "name_of_file.py", line 122, in upload_csv_to_bigquery
    job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
  File "/home/bongani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 660, in result
    return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/bongani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py", line 120, in result
    raise self._exception
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for imports per project. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors
```

I have emailed google support to try to increase the quota but they replied and said, they are unable to.

**My current implementation:**

```
import os
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed

from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery import LoadJobConfig

root_dir = "/path/to/some/directory"
dataset_id = 'dataset_namex'

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()


def upload_csv_to_bigquery(table_name, csv_full_path):
    s = time.time()
    load_config = LoadJobConfig()
    load_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
    table_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_name)
    with open(csv_full_path, 'rb') as source_file:
        job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_ref, job_config=load_config)  # API request
        job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
    print(f"upload time: {time.time() - s}")


def run():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as process_executor:
        futures = []
        for csvfile in os.listdir(root_dir):
            table_name = csvfile.split('_')[-1]
            futures.append(process_executor.submit(upload_csv_to_bigquery, table_name, root_dir + csvfile))
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            future.result()
    print("DONE!!!")


run()
```

This image shows the number of requests I make per sec, uploading. [Metrics from Google Cloud Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTiXf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make a script to read your CSVs row by row, and upload them using streaming inserts. The [limit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts) on streaming insterts is 100k rows/s or 100MB per second, whatever you reach first.

[`bigquery.tabledata.insertAll`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll) does not have rate limiting on the number of API calls, so it's a good option for uploading lots of small files that would make you reach the quota for [`bigquery.tables.insert`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me try that approach and see what happens.

Comment: I tried it out but then I can't stream dates outside the last 30 days in the past and 5 days in the future relative to the current date. All the tables are partitioned by date. And I have dates that go back to years ago.

Comment: This limitation is harder to overcome. If you have a column with the partition timestamp, try to import everything on a single table and then use a [partition expression](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#partition_expression) to move your now unpartitioned data (that is already in BQ), to a partitioned table. Note that [you can only affect up to 2k partitions in a single job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#partitioned_tables). If you need to modify lots of partitions, this could make your jobs to fail.